# Inheriting CSS properities causing an issue with Tablet layout?

Tags: css, layout, tablet, fluid-layout, inheritance

I've used the Dreamweaver Fluidlayout for this [website](http://irishbaubles.com/) however I'm having trouble trying to get the tablet layout on the index page to turn out like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DbRHA.jpg).

I'm currently at a mind block at what to do.  But I think it's about the inheriting of style properties.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the clear:both; that is making the icons stack up on top of each other in a single vertical column. And Maybe reduce the width and margin-left to allow them to line up in two columns. You may want to consider using a class for those elements since they are all ids yet using the same css properties. Inheritance only occurs with typographic css styles.